# Stackoverflow exception with Savefiledialog

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

I am receiving `Stackoverflow` exception when saving xml file with the help of `SaveFileDialog` in `WinForms` application. Code is nothing special:

```
DialogResult result = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(); 
if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    txtOutputFile.Text = saveFileDialog.FileName;
    // do something
}
```

It fails immediately in `ShowDialog()`.

I receive it only in the case I press Enter in the dialog after entering the name of file. If I press Save by mouse, everything works.

I received this exception on Windows 7 machine, tried on Windows 10 - everything works. Any ideas?

Update: I am sorry but I am not able to reproduce this issue now on the machine where I had for several days (in the same program, without any related changes).

Comment: Where is this code? Can you reproduce this in a short but complete program?

Comment: I will try to extract the related code and update my post

Comment: When do you show the dialog? In an event handler? If yes, what is the event? What is the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I show it in browseButton_Click, user presses ... button and dialog is being displayed. Will post stacktrace a little bit later also

Comment: Your program will be subjected to shell extensions.  DLLs that are loaded into your process when you use shell dialogs like OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog.  Pretty nasty code injection if you have one that's borken, it can certainly inject an SOE and get the process terminated.  You can see them getting loaded when you enable unmanaged code debugging.  Clean up your machine with SysInternals' AutoRuns.

Comment: @HansPassant I think you are right, I tried this issue again on the same environment but can't reproduce. Not sure what is the matter :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this thread trying to find a fix for the same problem.

I was able to solve the problem my targeting a specific architecture in my Build Configuration Manager.

Make sure that the configuration is set to either `x86` or `x64` and not `Any CPU`.